# Replace second derivative with product rule

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, map, code-request

Suppose that after some calculations, I find

```
a[x]*D[g[x],x,x]+b[x]*D[h[x],x,x]+c[x]*D[j[x],x]
```

What sort of operations do I need to do in Mathematica such that the output becomes

```
-D[a[x],x]*D[g[x],x]-D[b[x],x]*D[h[x],x]+c[x]*D[j[x],x]
```

This corresponds to making the replacement
\begin{align}
a(x)\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(a(x)\frac{dg}{dx}\right)-\frac{da}{dx}\frac{dg}{dx}
\end{align}
and ignoring the $\frac{d}{dx}\left(a(x)\frac{dg}{dx}\right)$ term.

In general, $g[x]$ and $h[x]$ can be anything, with the only commonality being that they are twice differentiated. I'm thinking that the solution will involved Replace[] and Map[], but I'm not sure how to apply them.

**Additional Information**

I am interested in terms like
\begin{align}
\frac{a_1(x)^{n_1}a_2(x)^{n_2}\cdots}{a_3(x)^{m_1}a_4(x)^{m_2}\cdots}\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}
\end{align}
where $a_1$ or $a_3$ might be $g(x)$ itself. Then, the Mathematica code should perform the operation:
\begin{align}
\frac{a_1(x)^{n_1}a_2(x)^{n_2}\cdots}{a_3(x)^{m_1}a_4(x)^{m_2}\cdots}\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}\to-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{a_1(x)^{n_1}a_2(x)^{n_2}\cdots}{a_3(x)^{m_1}a_4(x)^{m_2}\cdots}\right)\frac{dg}{dx}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code

```
rule = Derivative[2][f_][x_] g__ :> -D[f@x, x] D[Times@g, x];
a1[x]/g[x] D[g[x], x, x] + b[x] D[h[x], x, x] + c[x]^2 D[j[x], x, x]; /. rule;
```

which seems to do what you want. The difficulty was the peculiar `FullForm` of the `Derivative` function as seen in `rule`.

Comment: Ah, that's great! Thanks!

Comment: @user85503 Note the simpllification.